# Could a wizard research a death-reversal spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, wizard

In other words, is death-reversal (raise dead, resurrection, etc.) only the province of divine magic, or could a perhaps insanely powerful wizard (either player or NPC) research and cast a similar spell?

Comment: Historical note: In most earlier editions, the answer was "Yes, but arcane resurrections tend to have side effects." *Reincarnate* was an arcane spell, but you wouldn't be the same afterwards - and you *would* be the same afterwards with *clone*, but that was kind of the problem...

Answer (score 11):

First and foremost: **There are no rules that allow the researching of spells**. The only way a wizard can expand their repertoire is via the 2 spells gained at each level or by *finding* spells (PHB p.114).

This leads to the simple RAW answer: **No**

However, you can always fall back on How to Play (PHB p.6)

1. **The DM describes the environment** "Wizards do not get death-reversal spells and spells cannot be researched"
2. **The Players describe what they want to do** "I want my wizard to research a death-reversal spell. See it says on p. 201 that I can rediscover long lost spells."
3. **The DM narrates the results of the adventurers' actions** "Yes" or "No"

My personal preference is "No, if you want to do that play a druid or cleric"

As guidance for handling this specifically, the DM can look to Changing Spell Lists (DMG p.287), Creating a Spell (DMG p.283) and Crafting a Magic Item (DMG p.128).

**However, Wizards *can* cast death-reversal spells.** They do this through the spell *Wish* which can emulate any 8th level or lower spell; this includes every death reversal spell except *True Resurrection*.